# Segregating top spending customers

Tags: r

I have some data in the following format:

```
custno  TrainingType    TrainingDate    1   2   3   4   5   6
100     Presentation    2013-11-26    29.85  49.75  146.70  122.70  59.70   29.85
100     Presentation    2014-02-25    122.70 49.75  39.80   109.45  218.90  89.55
100     Training        2012-10-08    0.00   0.00   9.95    0.00    0.00    0.00
100     Training        2013-03-06    0.00   9.95   44.95   29.85   137.50  59.70
```

This is just the sample data and I have this data for thousands of customers with varying `custno`. The data in columns `1 through 6` represent the monthly spend in months `1 through 6`. I would like to segregate top 100 spending customers. In other words, I want the top 100 customers who spent the most across all months.

Here's the result of `dput(head(df))`:

```
structure(list(custno = c(100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L), 
    TrainingType = structure(c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("Demo", 
    "Presentation", "Tradeshow", "Training"), class = "factor"), 
    TrainingDate = structure(c(1385452800, 1393315200, 1349679600, 
    1362556800, 1366095600, 1372748400), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), `1` = c(29.85, 122.7, 0, 0, 9.95, 
    137.5), `2` = c(49.75, 49.75, 0, 9.95, 64.85, 49.75), `3` = c(146.7, 
    39.8, 9.95, 44.95, 97.7, 89.55), `4` = c(122.7, 109.45, 0, 
    29.85, 69.65, 99.5), `5` = c(59.7, 218.9, 0, 137.5, 69.65, 
    119.4), `6` = c(29.85, 89.55, 0, 59.7, 69.65, 29.85)), .Names = c("custno", 
"TrainingType", "TrainingDate", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), row.names = c(2L, 
3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Would anyone happen to know an intelligent way of doing it?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: So you want us to show you how to add six columns and then `aggregate` the sum by 'custno'? This is surely something you should have demonstrated some effort at searching SO or google and presenting initial coding efforts. It's also consider polite to post the example using `dput(head(your.data.frame.name))`

Comment: I updated the question with the result of `dput(head(df))`. I'm sorry for not including the initial coding effort. This is more of an idea question, I'm just wondering how to do it, not necessarily looking for the exact code for it.

Comment: One of the ideas that comes to my mind is to cluster the data and try to pick out the top customers. Not sure if that's the best though.

Comment: Here some hints: `tapply(rowSums(df[,4:9]),df$custno,sum)` will give you how much each customer is spending. Next you can `order` them to get the top 100.

Comment: @nicola: That looks like an excellent answer. Suggest you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tidydf <- gather(yourdata, month, spent, 4:9)

spendsum <- tidydf %>%
              group_by(custno) %>%
              summarise(
                totalspent = sum(spent)) %>%
              arrange(desc(totalspent))
```

Comment: I guess one additional line would be `slice(c(1:100))`. Then, you can choose top 100 customers.